# Which ResponseType should be used for the IHttpActionResult of a PUT or POST request?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I've started decorating my `IHttpActionResult` methods with a `[ResponseType]` attribute, with the intent of making it easier for the consumer to know what to do with the response.

That makes sense for GET, because I'll probably want to do something with the returned data.
But does `[ResponseType]` make any sense for PUT or POST requests, which don't return any data, just the success code?

e.g.

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("Contact/{contactId:int}/name", Name = "UpdateContactName")]
[ResponseType(typeof(?????))] // <- what should I put here? do I even need it at all?
public IHttpActionResult UpdateName(int contactId, [FromBody] string name)
{
    //...
    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As it turns out, `[ResponseType]` **does** make sense on controller methods that don't return data.

You can use a `void` type to ensure that the WebApi helpfile does not display a "sample not available" message for these methods.

i.e.

```
[ResponseType(typeof(void))]
```

Answer (score 1):

I might be missing something but I personally find the following approach much more elegant and informative

```
[HttpPut]
public IHttpActionResult Approve(long id)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {   
        return BadRequest();
    }
    // .....
    // .....



    bool success = false;// this is just a flag to indicate operation progress   

    // Do Update... 

    return Ok(sucess);
}
```

Rather than having a controller which doesn't return any data I would return *'something like'* Ok(true) depending on the success or failure of the operation.

Comment: But why would you ever return OK if the method fails? Also now the client needs to check the HTTP status code and also the content. Sorry but I don't think this makes sense.

Comment: If you read my response more carefully I have said "I would return 'something like' Ok(true) which indicates you can have other response types depending on the success or failure of  your operation. I edited the code to cover this point though. The whole point is client needs to be notified of his/her requested operation.